# Clear PrimeFaces TreeTable selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

How to implement a "Clear All Selection" button which will uncheck all selected things from a TreeTable implemented using PrimeFaces 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [client side API](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.TreeTable-1.html) for this. It allows you to `unselectAllNodes`. You can use it in combination with the `widgetVar` of your tree table:

```js
PF('yourWidgetVar').unselectAllNodes()
```

In a button, use it like:

```html
<p:button value="Clear selection"
          onclick="PF('yourWidgetVar').unselectAllNodes();return false"/>
```

Note that the linked documentation applies to the latest release, but the `unselectAllNodes` function is also present in 6.2:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_2/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.js#L701-L709

Comment: I used this way to implement the above unselectall
<script type="application/javascript">
 function unselectAllNodes() {
        </script>
Took the method from documentation tried declaring that in my xhtml code and calling it but wasnt working.
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/primefaces/request-context-execute.html